# harvard-thesis template and error using bm package

Tags: errors, templates

I have a following problem. I use harvard-thesis package to write my thesis and I have a problem, when I want to use a package bm. Here is a minimal example. Using this code:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{harvard-thesis}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx,xspace}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\newcommand{\todoMaciej}[1]{\todo[color=red!40]{\textsc{Maciej} says: #1}}
\newcommand{\todoPiotr}[1]{\todo[color=blue!40]{\textsc{Piotr} says: #1}}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,calc,through}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}



\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

$\bm{\alpha}$

\end{document}
```

I obtain a following error:

```
./thesis.tex:113 Undefined control sequence.
\Call@AtVeryEndDocument ...cumentHook \@undefined
                                                  \global \let \Call@AtVeryE...
l.113 $\bm{\alpha}
                  $
?
```

This error occurs with both LaTeX and XeLaTeX. I use as an editor TeXShop. Template I use can be found [here](https://github.com/suchow/LaTeX-template-for-Harvard-dissertation).

Comment: Please remove some of the irrelevant fluff from your example until you have a [minimal example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) exhibiting the error. All those commented out lines aren't relevant, and those custom math operators probably aren't either.

Comment: I am sorry for that. Is it ok, now?

Comment: Unrelated to the question but don't use `\usepackage{epsfig}` unless you are aiming to be compatible with the LaTeX 2.09 style of the same name, and have documents from the 1980's that you need to process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example isn't very minimal, I found a harvard-thesis class file on github, but it used other non standard packages and fonts I haven't got so I couldn't really run it.

However the main thing I think causing the problem is

```
\RequirePackage{mathspec}
```

I haven't looked at `mathspec` at all but I have looked at `unicode-math` and `bm` is largely incompatible with the extended math primitives in xelatex and luatex.

I have an extended version half finished that mostly works with xetex, but it still generated an error on your document.

If you are using unicode math fonts that have the math alphabet blocks (eg STIX, Cambria Math,..) Then you don't really need `bm` at all you can access bold alpha directly as unicode character U+1D6C2 ()

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After your answer I found out that harvard-thesis uses mathspec to display math fonts by Arno Pro font. With this package and XeLaTeX I believe I can use \mathbf with the same result as \bm. Please, tell me, if I am wrong.

Comment: @MaciekD that's what happens in unicode-math (internally it translates to the unicode code point I mentioned)